# why dynamic initialization occur before static initialization in gcc

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct NonConstant{
    NonConstant(int v):v_(v){
        std::cout<<"NonConstant\n";
    }
    int v_;
};

struct Constant{
    constexpr Constant(int v):v_(v){
        if(v_==0){
         std::cout<<"Constant\n";
        }
    }
    int v_;
};

NonConstant a = 2; //#1
Constant b = 0;   //#2

int main(){
}
```

The [outcome](https://godbolt.org/z/iLR7nC) will be:

```
NonConstant
Constant
```

I'm confused about this outcome, Becuase, According to the standard rules, `#1` is not static initialization, `#2` is, because of these:

> A constant initializer for a variable or temporary object o is an initializer whose full-expression is a constant expression, except that if o is an object, such an initializer may also invoke **constexpr constructors** for o and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types.
>   Constant initialization is performed if a variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constant initializer for the entity.If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration is zero-initialized. **Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization**;all other initialization is dynamic initialization. **All static initialization strongly happens before ([intro.races]) any dynamic initialization**.

The constructor of class `NonConstant` is not specified by constexpr, the initialization of `NonConstant a = 2;` will invoke a non-constexpr constructor for object `a`, hence, the initialization for `#1` is not static initialization, so it's a dynamic initialization. By contrast, the initialization of `Constant b = 0;` is a static initialization since the constructor be invoked is a constexpr constructor. And the rules say that **All static initialization strongly happens before  any dynamic initialization**. So, why the outcome implies that the evaluation of `#1` occured before that of `#2`? If I miss something, please correct me.

### UPDATE:

In the following comments of this question, someone says that except the constructor's class can be a non-literal type, the constexpr constructor  in any respects must be a valid core constant expression, that is,the invocation of `std::cout` will make the constexpr constructor not be a core constant expression. However,I have found another interpretation in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization), that is:

> Constant initialization is performed after (until C++14)instead of (since C++14) zero initialization of the static and thread-local objects and before all other initialization. Only the following variables are constant initialized:
>
> > 1. [...]
> > 2. Static or thread-local object of class type that is initialized by a constructor call, if the constructor is **constexpr and all constructor arguments (including implicit conversions) are constant expressions, and if the initializers in the constructor's initializer list and the brace-or-equal initializers of the class members only contain constant expressions**.

It does not say that the constexpr constructor must be a core constant expression. As long as the constructor be invoked satisfies that it's qualified by `constexpr` and it's arguments all must be constant expressions and member-initializer must be constant expressions.  So, `#2` is indeed a constant initialization, because the argument `0` is a constant expression and the selected constructor qualified by specifier `constexpr` and the member-initializer obey these rules mentioned in [expr.const](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214969/discussion-on-question-by-jack-x-why-dynamic-initialization-occur-before-static).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` has dynamic initialization, not static initialization.

As already explained by your quote of [[basic.start.static]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.static#2), `b` has static initialization only if the full-expression of its initializer, which is the execution of the `Constant(int)` constructor, is a constant expression.

In [[expr.const]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2), we read:

> An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - ...
> - an invocation of a function other than a constexpr constructor for a literal class, a constexpr function, or an implicit invocation of a trivial destructor ([class.dtor]) [ *Note:* Overload resolution is applied as usual  —  *end note* ] ;
> - ...

Here the evaluation of the constructor "following the rules of the abstract machine" includes the constructor body. And since the initializer is `0`, that evaluation would invoke `std::operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`, which is not `constexpr`. So the initializer's full expression is not a core constant expression and is not a constant expression.

And of course, though it's not the strictly technical definition, the entire point of "constant expression" is to define when we're guaranteed that the compiler can deal with something at compile time. And writing to the program's standard output certainly won't happen at compile time.

cppreference.com is a good resource that tries to be as accurate as possible, but it does not substitute for the authority of the actual Standard. That quote about constant initialization using a class constructor is incorrect for C++14 and C++17. I suspect it's actually left over from C++11, in which the body of a `constexpr` constructor was not allowed to evaluate any function calls at all, and [expr.const] similarly described requirements on uses of `constexpr` constructors within a core constant expression in terms of the member initializers.

Comment: you mean that the correct reading about the sentence after `except` is that, the constexpr constructor shall satisfy all requirements of a core constant expression in any other respects except that whether the constructor's class is a literal type or not,Right?

Comment: Yes, the "even if" phrasing limits the exception to that one reason for not being a constant expression.

Comment: thanks. before your answers, I misread the meaning of the sentence, however I still feel the sentence is unclear. i.e, the sentence may make an ambiguous for reader, especially, the wording `except` follow the `constant expression`, that would make reader understand it as, as long as the evaluted constructor is a constexpr constructor, then this case will be the exception.

Comment: Agree, there might be a way to phrase it more clearly.

Comment: `For an object, if the full-expression satisfy all requirements for a constant expression in any respects other than literal type, then it will be a static initialization` will more clear. :-)